# How to find the last entry and not the first when using INNER JOIN and CAST?

Tags: sqlite, casting, inner-join

My virtual radar program maintains a SQLite3 database. In the database are 2 tables, Aircraft and Flights. The first stores aircraft data and the other flights a particular aircraft made.
I'd like to get a list of aircraft that do not have a flight in the last 180 days.
Reading on the Internet I could create this query:

```
SELECT Registration,
       STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y',Flights.EndTime) AS 'Last Flight',
       Flights.Callsign,
       CAST ((JULIANDAY('now') - JULIANDAY(Flights.EndTime)) AS INTEGER) AS 
       'Days unseen'
FROM   Aircraft
       INNER JOIN Flights ON (Aircraft.AircraftID=Flights.AircraftID)
WHERE
       CAST ((JULIANDAY('now') - JULIANDAY(Flights.EndTime))AS INTEGER) >= 180
GROUP BY Registration
ORDER BY Flights.EndTime
```

The problem is that the Flights.EndTime is written in ascending order and the query thus looks at the first Flights.EndTime entry instead of the last one.
Is it possible to query the database and retrieve the list of aircraft that were not seen for 180 days or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this query:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AircraftID ORDER BY EndTime DESC) rn
FROM Flights
```

you can rank all the flights of each aircraft by `EndTime` descending.

If you join the above query to `Aircraft` and filter only the last flight (row number = 1), then there is no need for `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT a.Registration,
       STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y', f.EndTime) AS `Last Flight`,
       f.Callsign,
       CAST(JULIANDAY('now') - JULIANDAY(f.EndTime) AS INTEGER) AS `Days unseen`
FROM Aircraft a 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AircraftID ORDER BY EndTime DESC) rn
  FROM Flights  
) f ON a.AircraftID = f.AircraftID
WHERE f.rn = 1 AND CAST(JULIANDAY('now') - JULIANDAY(f.EndTime) AS INTEGER) >= 180
ORDER BY f.EndTime
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! I'll study your answer to learn it's exact logic.